# Mockito interfaces method clashing

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito, junit4

I have such code:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;

interface IListener<E> {
    void onEvent(E e);
}

interface MyListener extends IListener<String> {
    @Override
    void onEvent(String s);
}

public class XYZ {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyListener myListener = mock(MyListener.class);
        IListener<String> listener = myListener;
        listener.onEvent("XYZ");
        verify(myListener).onEvent(any(String.class));
    }

}
```

Which results in test failure. I understand, that overriding onEvent method in MyListener is excessive, but it's allowed by Java and could be done by 3rd party coders.

Could you explain, why it results in a test failure, while if MyListener doesn't override onEvent method everything works just fine.

Comment: What exactly does the failure message state? At first glance this seems like it should pass.

Comment: What happens if you use `myListener.onEvent("XYZ")` instead? Or `verify(listener).onEvent(any(String.class));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do:

```
IListener<String> listener = myListener;
listener.onEvent("XYZ");
```

it means `IListener`'s `.onEvent()` is called. But Mockito's proxy is over `MyListener`, and you redefine `.onEvent()` in the latter.

As a result, Mockito will not see your calls to `IListener`'s `.onEvent()`.

If you remove the override to `.onEvent()` in `MyListener` then it will work (why did you override it in the first place by the way?).

---

One way to do this would be to initiate your mock as an `IListener<String>`, not a `MyListener`.

Another way, but urgh. Note that your mock must be final for this to work.

```
    doAnswer(new Answer<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation)
            throws Throwable
        {
            final String o = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            myListener.onEvent(o);
            return null;
        }
    }).when((IListener<String>) myListener).onEvent(anyString());
```

Comment: I didn't. It's the 3rd party code I am using which is coded that weird way. But the point is, if it could be done in Java, there should be a way to test it.

Comment: Well, see answer, but your case is bizarre

Comment: There is another way actually, see answer

Comment: Yeah, but that's really ugly. One thing I haven't tried is to cast `myListener` into an `IListener` into `verify`; if it works it my avoid that kind of code...